# Why are some computer science conferences not included in the CORE ranking?

Tags: conference, computer-science, ranking, software-papers

So [CORE](http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks/) is the de facto standard benchmark to check the quality of a computer science conference.
However, there are some premier events that are not covered by this ranking.
For instance, I'm quite puzzled with the [IEEE International Conference on Software Analysis, Evolution and Reengineering (SANER)](https://saner2021.shidler.hawaii.edu). It will be the 28th edition of this conference in 2021, and yet SANER has not been included in CORE! What is more, it is a well-established venue, recognized in the software engineering community for the quality of the accepted research papers.
Any thoughts why SANER is not ranked A, or as a matter of fact not ranked at all?

Comment: "de facto standard benchmark" is to be taken with a grain of salt, especially since the ranking is a bit biased towards applied rather than theoretical conferences and the committee has made some much disputed decisions in the past. Good question, though.

Comment: I'm not sure that we here can answer why some organization has decided this or that. Perhaps the Australians just don't like IEEE?

Comment: I thought that CORE is dead.  If not, it's just dodgy.  Academics are simply including their favorite conferences into the list and using that to justify to the ARC that they perform world class research during ERA ranking.

Comment: @JonCuster more like the CS people do not like IEEE.

Comment: There are several very bad conferences. Some are outright fraudulent (WASET). There are several other factors involved in conference ratings - many of them political in nature. It's best to look at the proceedings of the conference and judge for yourself if it is a good conference. That way you can avoid most of the politics involved.

Comment: I'm told conferences must apply to be ranked by CORE. A conference may not be listed simply because the organizers haven't done so.

Comment: Adding to the point by @Thomas : The organizers may be reluctant to receive a poor ranking and thus prefer to not apply for one.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is because SANER was called WCRE before (present for example in core 2018, ranked B which seems right to me) and changed name. From experience, CORE people do not change things by themselves, it is better to send them update requests

Comment: Regarding update requests, one might mention that there is a formal process for that: within certain submission periods, conferences can apply for a (re-)ranking. They can apply for a specific rank, and then need to present evidence that they fulfill the [criteria](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y2IpHLE9401p_h-UoiKdfg13FOUdNUE6/view) for that rank. Often, the decision committee eventually ranks the conference lower than applied for. It's very plausible that some conferences prefer to not apply because they are reluctant to receive a poor ranking.

Answer (score 2):

CORE is NOT a "de facto standard benchmark" to check the quality of a computer science conference. Ranking academic research based on where it was published without having a read through the actual work and understanding its impact will end up in bigotry and corruption. The community that I respect and appreciate working with does not care about CORE ranking.